# How can the temperature of stars can be determined by their color?

Tags: star, fundamental-astronomy, temperature

How do you determine the temperature of a star by color?

Comment: You got it backwards. Stars are black body radiators, so their color is determined mostly by their temperature. Coldest stars are red. Intermediate temperatures are: orange, yellow, and white. Hottest stars are blue.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a H-R diagram? They often have expected colours of stars on them too. If this is a homework assignment, I'd be surprised if it hasn't come up before now.

Comment: The question is a good one, but we frown on doing people's homework for them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework (and time-sensitive)

Comment: @FlorinAndrei  that's a bit too simplified, seeing as "white" is not a color.  As you know, the temperature calculation is based on the peak output wavelength.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's a 3-line comment, of course it's simplified.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Careful please with labeling this as homework - that is not at all obvious.

Comment: @JanDoggen at the time I wrote that,  the text said something like "Please answer ASAP because worksheet is due"

Comment: Sometimes I really don't understand how this site is operated. Even if it is a homework question, it is still a question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about color index and temperature. So, I will briefly explain under that circumstance.

Color index, e.g., B-V is the difference in brightness (magnitude) of the light observed by filters B and V. (The following discussion can be generalized to other color indeces, e.g., U-B or g-i). Filters B and V have effective wavelengths 4450 (bluer) and V 5510 (redder) A (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system)), respectively, therefore B-V increases when the object becomes red. (Recall that magnitude is more negative for being brighter). The temperature which is derived from the color index is called "color temperature;" this is different to blackbody temperature, or kinetic temperature, or other types of inferred temperatures (see [this [2](https://www.physics.byu.edu/faculty/christensen/Physics%20427/FTI/Measures%20of%20Temperature.htm)).

For the color temperature, this is very observational inference. To map from the color index to the color temperature, it is inferred from other well-known object. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_index) for this.

Another way to work around is to transform the color index into the flux ratio, then applying the blackbody function as the inference. For example, from B-V >>> flux(4450A)/flux(5510A) >>> blackbody temperature corresponding to the flux ratio.